# Godaddy cron job sends only one email

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron

I am trying to run a cron job that executes the following PHP code:

```
<?php
require 'public_html/db.php';
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$aa = mysql_query("SELECT * from send where sent='0' LIMIT 20");

while($rw = mysql_fetch_array($aa)) {

$id = $rw ['id'];
$email = $rw ['email'];
$nick_sent= $rw ['nick'];
$nick_rw = $rw ['nick_pr'];

require 'public_html/mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('info@mymail.com', 'Email');
$mail->addReplyTo('info@mymail.com', 'Email');
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Message';

$mail->Body = 'My message';

$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
if ($mail->send()) {

    mysql_query("UPDATE send SET sent = '1' WHERE id='$id'");}
}   
?>
```

If I access the file directly via my browser, it works perfect. However, if running it via a cron job, it will only execute the while code ONCE...meaning it only pulls the first row out of the MySQL database and sends ONE email, when it should be pulling multiple rows and sending multiple emails. Can you guys help me? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe GoDaddy prevents sending more than one email from within cron?  Try putting the number of rows returned in you email to see what actually is returned by the query.

Comment: may be bulk mail prevented by  your service provider .ask godaddy

Comment: please use require_once instead of require, and take it out from the loop

Comment: Thank you very much @Yair.R . It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, you are initialise the PHPMailer object again and again. Kindly update your code as per below.

```
<?php
require 'public_html/db.php';
require 'public_html/mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('info@mymail.com', 'Email');

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$aa = mysql_query("SELECT * from send where sent='0' LIMIT 20");

while($rw = mysql_fetch_array($aa)) 
{

$id = $rw ['id'];
$email = $rw ['email'];
$nick_sent= $rw ['nick'];
$nick_rw = $rw ['nick_pr'];


$mail->addReplyTo('info@mymail.com', 'Email');
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Message';

$mail->Body = 'My message';

$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
if ($mail->send()) {

    mysql_query("UPDATE send SET sent = '1' WHERE id='$id'");}
}   
$mail->clearAddresses();
}
?>
```